# 'Commit to Branch' option in XCode 6

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode6

In earlier versions of XCode, there was an option called `Commit to Branch` on commit page which really helped when you'd messed around too much with your code in a particular branch and didn't want to commit it into the same branch and neither did you want to lose all the code that you'd written.

I couldn't find this option in XCode 6. Is it still there hidden somewhere, or have they removed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excerpt from the "Save and Revert Changes" section of the Apple IOS Devloper's library

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ManageChanges.html

> Create a Branch to Isolate Risky Changes
>
> After you’ve worked on a project for a while, you are likely to have a
>   body of reliable, stable code. You can choose Source Control > Working
>   Copy > New Branch to create a copy of that code. Then you can work on
>   new features and other changes without destabilizing your existing
>   code base. When you are satisfied with your changes, you can merge
>   them back into the body of stable code. **Use Source Control > Working
>   Copy > Merge from Branch and Source Control > Working Copy > Merge
>   into Branch to combine and reconcile differences between versions of
>   your project.**